# How to locate the product ID in the product-container using selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to crawl the product IDs in a website, while the ID locate in the product container. It return no such element:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('na finger product-container')
```

HTML:

```
<div data-v-8cd3b522="" na-element="item" na-module="product" na-data="{“ids_value”:[“#300#”],”ids_key”:”item_type_ids”,”item_type_ids”:[“#300#”],”tag_ids”:[“#85#”],”app_page_section_id”:10103,”app_page_id”:10011}" class="na finger product-container" na-id="9cd1a902-57aa-48d4-b79c-2bca03d21b83">
```

The attribute I wanted to retrieve is the `ids_value` which is `#300#` in this case.

the website: https://www.gratus.com.hk/product/

[image: the html example]

Comment: Which attribute you want `na-id`?

Comment: the attribute i wanted is the the "ids_value" which is "#300#" in the case

Comment: It is a good idea to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , so other users can paste your code and answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `@class` as identifier try search by single class name

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-container')
```

or by CSS selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.na.finger.product-container')
```

You might also need to implement [Implicit/Explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) as required data seem to be dynamic

Comment: can locate the individual product div using "driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.na.finger.product-container')", but how to access to {"ids_value":"300"} inside the "na-data"?

Comment: .get_attribute('na-data') then maybe parsing.

Answer (score 0):

To parse out the tag.

```
import json
elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.na.finger.product-container').get_attribute('na-data')
myJSON = json.loads(elem)
print(myJSON["ids_value"])
```

Outputs

```
['#290#']
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the `ids_value` e.g. *290*, *291* etc, from all of the `<div>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("na-data").split("#")[1] for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[na-element='item'][na-module='product']")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("na-data").split("#")[1] for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@na-element='item' and @na-module='product']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['290', '291', '292', '295', '296', '297', '298', '299', '300', '302', '303', '305', '306', '307', '308', '309']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -1):

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.na.finger.product-container').get_attribute('na-data')

return

{"ids_value":["#290#"],"ids_key":"item_type_ids","item_type_ids":["#290#"],"tag_ids":["#4#"],"app_page_section_id":10103,"app_page_id":10011}

thanks everyone!